# Склонение числительных

Tags: числительные

Одинаково или по-разному пишутся два сходных выражения:
(1) прибавить к пяти целым двум десятым, (2) прибавить к нулю целым/целых двум десятым.
Как правильно объяснить решение?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

В Грамматике 80 приводится ДВА ВИДА КЛАССИФИКАЦИИ числительных: по семантическому и грамматическому принципам. По грамматической классификации к числительным относятся только количественные и собирательные числительные, для которых соблюдается следующий закон: В И.-В. ПАДЕЖЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ УПРАВЛЯЕТ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМ, А В ОСТАЛЬНЫХ ПАДЕЖАХ СОГЛАСУЕТСЯ С НИМИ.

Слово ноль относится к числительным по семантической классификации, но по грамматической классификации – это ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ,  поэтому оно ведет себя как обычное существительное. Это означает, что ноль в качестве главного слова УПРАВЛЯЕТ Р.п. отнесенных к нему слов (к нулю ЦЕЛЫХ, с нулем ЦЕЛЫХ). В тех же косвенных падежах ОБЫЧНОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ СОГЛАСУЕТСЯ со словом «целые»: к пяти целым, с пятью целыми.

Comment: Оказывается, вопрос такой уже задавался!)))  
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8787/морфология-дробные-числительные  
Мой ответ идентичен ответу @olsa

Comment: Грумант, вы великолепны в своем стремлении что-нибудь сказать.
Сколько вам потребуется времени, чтобы сходить по ссылке в ответе, на который Вы ссылаетесь?

Вот настоящий ответ **olsa**, то, что Вы даете - всего лишь пример использования "правила". 
http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8775

Ну то, что Ваш ответ весьма далек от того, на который Вы ссылаетесь - это уж к бабке не ходи. Но все-таки там нет ни малейшей попытки обосновать управление тем, что ноль якобы числительное, - это-то Вы видите?

Comment: София, ловить Ваши постоянные комментарии в тексте очень 
трудно. Почему Вы не пользуетесь комментариями?

>Слово ноль ... ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ,   
  
Все это очень интересно, но почему мы вслед за Грумантом должны пользовать именно "грамматическую классификацию"? Да еще так неаккуратно, относя к ней только ноль? Есть нормальная формулировка *"числительные миллион, миллиард (а так же ноль, сотня и проч.) имеют грамматическую связь по типу существительного, т.е. **управляют** существительных с ним связанным "*. Чего ради огород городить?

Comment: Здесь речь идет о том, что слова ноль, а также тысяча, миллион, миллиард, мы традиционно (с точки зрения семантики)считаем числительными, но, с точки зрения грамматики, это существительные, так как они обладают всеми грамматическими категориями существительных и не имеют признаков, отличных от существительных. Именно эта информация дает возможность решить предложенную задачу.

Comment: Ответ @olsa ( Если в дроби целых единиц — ноль, то при её склонении слово «целых» не изменяется. Температура приблизилась к нолю целых пяти десятым градуса http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8787/морфология-дробные-числительные) из того же источника: http://newslab.ru/blog/437279

Comment: Что-то не видно тут других "рыдающих".
Кстати, Вы действительно полагаете, что аналогия или иллюстрация может служить доказательством?

Answer (score 3):

А чем отличаются числительные "пять" и "ноль"? Давайте посмотрим с математической точки зрения. Мы имеем пять (ноль) целых частей и две десятые части от целого. Давайте пока отбросим десятые и просклоняем только целые.
Кому-чему? — пяти (нулю) целым. И, соответственно, двум десятым.
Вот и ответ.

Comment: А если так: сложить с пятью целыми или с нулем целых/целыми?

Comment: Сложить - с **нулем целых (частей)**. 
Но - с **пятью целыми (частями)**.

И на этой форме никак не сказывается наличие дробной части.
Подробнее - у меня в ответе.

>Кому-чему? — пяти (нулю) целым  
Нет.  
Пяти цел***ым***, но нулю цел***ых***.
Десяти зелен**ым** лягушк**ам**, но миллиону зелен**ых** лягуш**ек**.
Пять - как десять, ноль - как миллион.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос на самом деле. Тут проявляется особенность грамматической связи с существительными у числительных. Главное: ноль - он ведет себя не как "пять", он как "миллион".
Плюс к этому надо иметь в виду, что "целая" это сокращение от "целая доля" (или честь).

И. Пять(десять, сорок) целых (частей) и две десятых (части) яблока.
Р. Пяти(десяти, сорока) целых (частей) и двух десятых (частей) яблока.
Д. Пяти(десяти, сорока) цел***ым***(част***ям***) и двум десятым (частям) яблока.

и т.д.

И. Ноль(миллион, миллиард) целых (частей) и две десятых (части) яблока.
Р. Ноля(миллиона, миллиарда) целых (частей) и двух десятых (частей) яблока.
Д. Нолю(миллиону, миллиарду) цел***ых*** (част***ей***) и двум десятым (частям) яблока.

и т.д.

"Тысяча" испытывает колебания в формах, ранее согласовывалась как десять (кошелек с двумя тысячами рублями), сейчас почти повсеместно управляет как миллион (кошелек с двумя тысячами рублей), это огромная тема, я здесь опускаю.
Особенности грамматической связи для "один" и "два-четыре" - тоже в другой раз, хотя с ними не так все и сложно.

Если все еще непонятно, замените "целые части" на "белых мышей". Полная аналогия.

И. Пять(десять, сорок) белых мышей.
Р. Пяти(десяти, сорока) белых мышей.
Д. Пяти(десяти, сорока) бел***ым*** мыш***ам***.

и т.д.

И. Ноль(миллион, миллиард) белых мышей.
Р. Ноля(миллиона, миллиарда) белых мышей.
Д. Нолю(миллиону, миллиарду) бел***ых*** мыш***ей***.

и т.д.

*(Я вырвался сюда ненадолго, участвовать в бесконечных дебатах ни о чем, подобно тому, как имело место в "долях квартиры", не имею возможности, постарайтесь конкретно).*